# Output of Requests for API in JSON/Dictionary format

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am very new to APIs. I am trying to get the response of a requests.post method in the form of a json file or dictionary. I get a status_code of 200, so I know there is success, but when I run response.text I return everything as a string. I have read parts of the Quickstart guide for Requests, but they only seem to use .text to extract the data. My expected output for this particular api would ideally be a json file or some dictionary I can work with.

What I have so far (I get this is not a full reproducible example, but I think it gets the point across, otherwise refer to [here for some examples](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/)):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
response = requests.post(
    url = request_url
    ,headers = headers
    ,json = body
)
response.text # returns a string
response.json # returns a method
pd.json_normalize(response.text) #throws an error that pandas does not have this attribute (which it does, idk why not)
pd.read_json(response.text) #somewhat workable dataframe.
```

`pd.read_json()` gets me somewhere, but it is an object in a cell of a dataframe, which I feel like is not the route to go down on.

Comment: `response.json()` (note the parentheses) will return a python dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on John Gordon's comment above, you can do the following

```
data = response.json()
```

Then with from pandas.io.json import json_normalize you can also do

```
df = json_normalize(data)
```

This will convert the response into a pandas dataframe.